# Pre-defined color cycles à la RColorBrewer?

Tags: pgfplots, color

When I have multiple line plots in `pgfplots`, the colors of the lines cycle through a few  colors (my guess is the colors are blue, red, black and dark khaki) before repeating with different marks. See below:

[image]

However, in my opinion these default colors are not very nice. For example, compare the colors used by [Color Brewer](http://colorbrewer2.org/) for qualitative data.

Based on the following [link](http://timotheepoisot.fr/2012/07/03/colorbrewer-in-pgfplots/), I know enough about how to define my own line color styles in `pgfplots`. For example,

```
\definecolor{s1}{RGB}{228, 26, 28}
\definecolor{s2}{RGB}{55, 126, 184}
\definecolor{s3}{RGB}{77, 175, 74}
\definecolor{s4}{RGB}{152, 78, 163}
\definecolor{s5}{RGB}{255, 127, 0}
\pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist{set1}{
    s1,every mark/.append style={fill=s1},mark=*\\
    s2,every mark/.append style={fill=s2},mark=*\\
    s3,every mark/.append style={fill=s3},mark=*\\
    s4,every mark/.append style={fill=s4},mark=*\\
    s5,every mark/.append style={fill=s5},mark=*\\
}
```

Before defining my own color schemes, I was wondering if someone had already done this as a LaTeX/`pgfplots` package? If not, would this be a useful feature that could be incorporated in a future version of `pgfplots`?

Comment: There are already a couple of different cycle lists in PGFPlots (try `cycle list name=exotic`, or `color list`). I've also used the ColorBrewer "Blues" scheme [in one answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26054/default-color-pgfplot), "Accent" [in another](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37568/colors-and-legend-in-groupplots), and "YellowGreenBlue" [in yet another](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116765/particular-bar-plot-with-pgfplots-bar-color-category). I think it would be nice to have these pre-packaged, but keep in mind that the schemes are made for *maps*, not...

Comment: ... line plots, so a lot of the schemes (especially the diverging and sequential ones) don't work particularly well for line plots because they contain very light colours. Some adjustments might be necessary to make this work properly.

Comment: What you want to have sounds a lot like continuos color maps, something that pgfplots supports for colored plots. In principle, it should be possible to define suitable color maps and to retrieve color values in order to prepare cycle lists (compare http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44868/drawing-heatmaps-using-tikz/83865#83865)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

*This is an edit of [Stefan Pinnow](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/95441/stefan-pinnow):*

*Jake is referring to a **non-PGFPlots**/external colorbrewer library of (I guess LoopSpace). For the **PGFPlots**/internal colorbrewer library please have a look at [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/350086/95441).*

---

There is now a [PGFPlots library `colorbrewer`](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~tex-sx/tex-sx/development/view/head:/tikzlibrarypgfplots.colorbrewer.code.tex) that creates cycle lists using the colorbrewer color schemes. The color values are taken from the [ColorBrewer Excel file](http://www.personal.psu.edu/cab38/ColorBrewer/ColorBrewer_RGB.html).

To set a colorbrewer cycle list, you call `colorbrewer cycle list=<scheme>`, which will define the necessary colors (`colorbrewer1` to `colorbrewer8`) and create a cycle list called `colorbrewer`.

The number of colors and plot styles that are defined can be set using the key `colorbrewer values=<number>`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}   
\usepgfplotslibrary{colorbrewer}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    colorbrewer cycle list=Dark2
]
\addplot {rnd};
\addplot {rnd-1};
\addplot {rnd-2};
\addplot {rnd-3};
\addplot {rnd-4};
\addplot {rnd-5};
\addplot {rnd-6};
\addplot {rnd-7};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Here's an overview of the color schemes:

[image]  [image] [image] [image]

Comment: This is great! I would like to accept your answer, but am not sure whether I should wait for someone (perhaps yourself) to provide a full answer?

Comment: @ILiketoCode: I've uploaded a PGFPlots library file to the ["From Answers to Packages"](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2740/from-answers-to-packages) repository that can be used to create cycle lists now. Next step is creating colormaps.

Comment: @Jake: This is beautiful! I'm using it now for my MSc thesis. Thank you! I can't wait for the colormaps.

Comment: Jake's answer was not working for me. Neither on ShareLatex nor my local TexLive distribution. On both I would get the error message "I do not know the key /tikz/colorbrewer cycle list". I have to add `\pgfplotsset{cycle list/Dark2}` in the preample, and not use `colorbrewer cycle list`.

Comment: @Roald 's suggestion works, but it doesn't provide markers for the data points. For this you should refer to the manual as suggested by Stefan below, in particular the `cycle multiindex* list` setting.

Answer (score 13):

**Just for the record**

Since v1.13 PGFPlots provides the ColorBrewer color schemes itself in the corresponding library `colorbrewer`. Because I don't want to repeat the manual I want to refer to it. It are only 4 pages to read and about two of them consist of images from what I'll repeat some of them here.

**Edit**

In the meantime I have answered several questions where I used  the `colorbrewer` library. Here are some of them you can study, if you don't want to read the manual or have some practical code to play with:

- questions regarding `cycle list`s

  - [colorbrewer with pgfplot 1.15](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/425494/colorbrewer-with-pgfplot-1-15/425496#425496)
  - [colorbrewer cycle list not showing markers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/425584/colorbrewer-cycle-list-not-showing-markers/425588#425588)
  - [How can I reverse a cycle list in pgfplots?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/427332/how-can-i-reverse-a-cycle-list-in-pgfplots/427348#427348)
  - [Plot a stacked bar plot with specialised x axis range](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/425963/plot-a-stacked-bar-plot-with-specialised-x-axis-range/426065#426065)
- questions regarding `colormap`s

  - [Diverging color scale for a table heatmap](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/368751/diverging-color-scale-for-a-table-heatmap/368756#368756)
  - [pgfplots - surf - Standard color schemes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/350905/pgfplots-surf-standard-color-schemes/350927#350927)
  - [PGFPlots 3D: cannot use most of the colormaps for the interior colormap](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/327450/pgfplots-3d-cannot-use-most-of-the-colormaps-for-the-interior-colormap/327455#327455)
  - [GIS layer maps from .dat files and not figures](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/371141/gis-layer-maps-from-dat-files-and-not-figures/372105#372105)

---

[image: image showing the "Sequential Schemes" of the ColorBrewer library]

[image: image showing the "Diverging Schemes" of the ColorBrewer library]

[image: image showing the "Qualitative Schemes" of the ColorBrewer library]