# PGFPlots 3D: cannot use most of the colormaps for the interior colormap

Tags: pgfplots, 3d

How can I use all colormaps from the `colormaps` library for the interior colormap? Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colormaps}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    height=10cm,
hide axis,
xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
]
\addplot3[domain=-1.5:1.5,opacity=0.7,surf,colormap/cold,
%mesh/interior colormap name=hot, %works
mesh/interior colormap name=gray, %doesn't work
]
{-exp(-x^2-y^2)};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to "load" the colormaps from the `colormaps` library explicitly before use (The same is true for the colormaps of the `colorbrewer` library.) So your question isn't really related to 3D plots ...

Here your code again with two valid positions to "load" the colormap.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usepgfplotslibrary{colormaps}
    \pgfplotsset{
        compat=1.13,
        % either load the colormap here ...
%        colormap/gray,
    }
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            height=10cm,
            hide axis,
            xlabel=$x$,
            ylabel=$y$,
            % ... or here
            colormap/gray,
        ]
            \addplot3[
                domain=-1.5:1.5,
                opacity=0.7,
                surf,colormap/cold,
                %mesh/interior colormap name=hot, %works
                mesh/interior colormap name=gray, %doesn't work
            ] {-exp(-x^2-y^2)};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]