# pgfplots - surf - Standard color schemes

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, color

Are there standard color schemes defined for surface plots of `pgfplots`?

Like the `summer`, `winter`, `jet` etc.. of `Matlab`.

[Matlab colormap](https://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colormap.html)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There are a lot of standard colormaps defined in PGFPlots. For that have a look at at the PGFPlots manual (v1.14)

- section ["Predefined Colormaps"](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf#page=194) which is a subsection of section 4.7.6 on page 194,
- section [5.3 Colormaps](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf#page=419) on page 419, which is the description of the library with the same name and provides colormaps of the free Matlab package "SC -- powerful image rendering" of Oliver Woodford, and
- section [5.2 ColorBrewer](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf#page=414) which shows how to access the famous colormaps from http://colorbrewer2.org.

Of course you can also create your own colormaps either from scratch or combine colormaps from already existing ones or newly created. Here I present an example which is copied from the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf#page=165)

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{
        compat=1.14,
    }
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            view={0}{90},
            colormap={whiteblue}{color=(blue) color=(white)},
            colormap={gb}{color=(green) color=(yellow)
                color=(brown)},
            colorbar horizontal,
            colorbar style={minor x tick num=1},
            y dir=reverse,
        ]
            %  The table file is packed into the archive
            % `doc/latex/pgfplots/pgfplots.doc.src.tar.bz2'
            \addplot3 [
                contour filled={
                    levels from colormap={
                        of colormap={
                            whiteblue,
                            target pos max=,
                            target pos={-12000,-10000,-6000,
                                -5000,-3000,-1000,-750,-500,
                                -250,-100,-50,0}
                        },
                        of colormap={
                            gb,
                            target pos min=,
                            target pos={10,100,200,500,1000,
                                1100,1200, 1500,2000,4000,
                                6000,8000}
                        },
                    },
                },
            ] table {heightmap.dat};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: oyf... you accidentally picked the worst but works well for such data

Comment: @percusse, I chose this because it shows a lot of the possibilities that can be "done" with colormaps in PGFPlots. That are in this case: 1. You can create your own colormaps, 2. you can combine different colormaps, 3. they can be "sampled" (linearly), and 4. they can be sampled non-linearly.

Answer (score 20):

For a quick solution, I add the following here (activate with `\pgfplotsset{colormap/<name>}`):

```
viridis
```

[image]

```
hot
```

[image]

```
hot2
```

[image]

```
jet
```

[image]

```
blackwhite
```

[image]

```
bluered
```

[image]

```
cool
```

[image]

```
greenyellow
```

[image]

```
redyellow
```

[image]

```
violet
```

[image]

Comment: Where can I find these? I am preparing a cheat sheet and I would like to create a table with the maps.

Comment: If you haven't found it yet: https://mirror.szerverem.hu/ctan/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf#page=424