# how to specify colors as RGB right in the plot definitions

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Within a tikzpicture environment I want to denote several plotted curves each with a different color.   If I use the syntax for each curve such as the following it works fine.

```
\addplot[color=olive] coordinates { 
(2, 0.0) 
(2, 0.0) 
(4, 0.0) 
(4, 0.0) 
(4, 0.0) 
(12, 0.0) 
);
```

However, I would like to specify the color by rgb rather than having to only select from predefined colors.  Why?  because my plots are machine generated, and I can compute a set of n colors for n graphs.   And I'd like to avoid having to synchronize my latex file color definitions with my program which generates plot file.

I've tried several formats, all which die horrible deaths.

```
\addplot[color=0x89abcd] coordinates { ...}   
\addplot[color=#89abcd] coordinates { ...}   
\addplot[color=89abcd] coordinates { ...}   
\addplot[color=\color[rgb]{81,82,83}] coordinates { ...}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on what you mean by "my plots are machine generated, and I can compute a set of n colors for n graphs" please. So you want to replicate already existing plots with PGFPlots and you want to use exactly the same color?

Comment: Elaboration:  I have code which generates a set of .ltxdat files which I  include in my latex document via \input{filexyz.ltxdat}.   I have several different latex files which input different overlapping subsets of the various .ltxdat files.    Each .ltxdat file uses one \begin{tikzpicure} ...\end{tikzpicture} do define some number of plots, each file having potentially a different number of plots.    Depending on the number of curves, I chose a set of colors which are "visibly different", and I set the color of each addplot accordingly.

Does that help?

Comment: Could you have your code write `\definecolor{col1}{RGB}{81,82,83}` to the start of the `tikzpicture` and then use `\addplot[color=col1] ..`? Other than that, would writing options to the `axis` be a possibility? I think (but I'm not sure) that colours have to be named colours, but you could generate a colourmap with RGB colours, and make a `cycle list` based on the colourmap.

Comment: If the correct answer is that "No, it is not possible", then sigh, that's the answer.   

Does it hurt anything if I end up defining the same color many times and they all get included in the latex file?    Or do I need to try to only define each color once?

Comment: If you define a colour inside a `tikzpicture` environment it won't be available outside it, but I don't think it hurts to have multiple definitions.

Comment: Since PGFPlots v1.13 the famous ColorBrewer cycle lists are included as library, where are already different presets for different number of lines. E.g. have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/350086/95441 or at the [PGFPlots manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf#page=418). Would that help? If this might be an option I could add an answer with a use case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think what you're asking is possible (edit: perhaps not directly, but see [percusse's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/409748/)). The `pgfplots` manual section 4.7.5 *Colors* indicates that colours have to be defined with e.g. `\definecolor` before use. Further, the `color` key belongs to TikZ, and the manual for TikZ/`pgf` section 15.2 *Specifying a color* says of `/tikz/color=<color name>` that

> The `<color name>` is the name of a previously defined color.

---

What you could do is have your code write a series of `\definecolor` statements into each file, with colors named e.g. `clr1`, `clr2` etc., and use `\addplot [clr1]...` etc.

Another possibility could be to define a new `colormap`, RGB colors can be used for that, and make a new `cycle list` based on that `colormap`. I'm not sure if this is any better though, I'm just throwing it out.

Both `tikzpicture`s in the code below generate the same output:

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
% Define colours inside tikzpicture environment:
\begin{tikzpicture}
\definecolor{clr1}{RGB}{81,82,83}
\definecolor{clr2}{RGB}{31,182,83}
\definecolor{clr3}{RGB}{31,18,213}
\begin{axis}[
  height=4cm,ymin=-1,ymax=3
]
\addplot [clr1, line width=5mm] coordinates { 
(2, 0.0) 
(4, 0.0) 
};

\addplot [clr2, line width=5mm] coordinates { 
(2, 1.0) 
(4, 1.0) 
};

\addplot [clr3, line width=5mm] coordinates { 
(2, 2.0) 
(4, 2.0) 
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

% Define a new colormap and make a cycle list based on that
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  colormap={foo}{
     % make a list of N colors
     rgb255(1)=(81,82,83);
     rgb255(2)=(31,182,83);
     rgb255(3)=(31,18,213);
  },
  % use 0,...,N-1 
  cycle list={[indices of colormap={0,...,2} of foo]},
  % the following two lines just for example
  height=4cm,ymin=-1,ymax=3,
  every axis plot/.append style={line width=5mm}
]

\addplot coordinates { 
(2, 0.0) 
(4, 0.0) 
};

\addplot coordinates { 
(2, 1.0) 
(4, 1.0) 
};

\addplot coordinates { 
(2, 2.0) 
(4, 2.0) 
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make up your own color setter via some keys but I think setting up a proper colormap as Torbjørn showed is a more structured solution.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[define rgb/.code={\definecolor{mycolor}{RGB}{#1}},
                    rgb color/.style={define rgb={#1},mycolor}]
\begin{axis}[height=4cm,ymin=-1,ymax=3]
\addplot [rgb color={81,81,81}, line width=5mm] coordinates { (2, 0) (4, 0) };
\addplot [rgb color={81,182,83}, line width=5mm] coordinates { (2, 1) (4, 1) };
\addplot [rgb color={31,18,213}, line width=5mm] coordinates { (2, 2) (4, 2) };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I can't figure out how to get code formatting in a comment.

Here is what I decided to do, which seems to work.  Before each \addplot I insert a \definecolor with a machine generated name.

   \definecolor{color008941}{RGB}{0,137,65}
   \addplot[color=color008941] coordinates {
    (4, 0.0)  
    (9, 0.0)  
    (16, 0.0)
    };
    \definecolor{color6}{RGB}{0,111,166}
    \addplot[color=color6] coordinates {
    (1, 0.0)
    (36, 0.001)
    };
    \definecolor{color7}{RGB}{122,73,0}  
    \addplot[color=color7] coordinates {
    (16, 0.0)
    (100, 0.003)
    };

Comment: @JimNewton That's what I'm doing too. but only as a keyword to `addplot`