# colorbrewer with pgfplot 1.15

Tags: pgfplots, color, installing

I would like to use `colorbrewer` with `pgfplots` to nicely color some graphs in my document. However, this minimal working example [given in the answer to another question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119161/pre-defined-color-cycles-%C3%A0-la-rcolorbrewer/350086)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}   
\usepgfplotslibrary{colorbrewer}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    colorbrewer cycle list=Dark2,
]
\addplot {rnd};
\addplot {rnd-1};
\addplot {rnd-2};
\addplot {rnd-3};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

throws this error:

> ./Plots.tex:47: Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key
>   '/tikz/colorbrewer cycle list', to which you passed 'Dark2', and I am
>   going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

I assume the error comes from an incorrect installation of [the relevant files from Github](https://github.com/vtraag/tikz-colorbrewer). I am currently using MacOS.

I followed the installation steps and copied all files to a folder I created in

```
/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex/colorbrewer
```

and ran the texhash command - to no avail.

**Why can't I get nice colors in my pgfplot plots? Am I at least correct in assuming that the installation is the cause of my troubles, or is the library already included in the colorbrewer package?**

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](//tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You shouldn't have to install the library separately, it is included with `pgfplots`. But you should use `cycle list/Dark2`, not `colorbrewer cycle list=Dark2`.

Output with `ultra thick`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}   
\usepgfplotslibrary{colorbrewer}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    cycle list/Dark2,
]
\addplot {rnd};
\addplot {rnd-1};
\addplot {rnd-2};
\addplot {rnd-3};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Still gives me the error: "I do not know the key '/tikz/cycle list/Dark2'". Just found out, that it works if I use "cycle list name=Dark-2".

Answer (score 3):

You first have to *load* the `colormap`/`cycle list` which is done by `colormap/<colormap name`/`cycle list/<cycle list name>`.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.15
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usepgfplotslibrary{colorbrewer}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        % activates the `cycle list', i.e. it is initialized and selected
        % (this will also initialize the associated `colormap', but doesn't
        %  select it)
        cycle list/Dark2,
    ]
        \addplot {rnd};
        \addplot {rnd-1};
        \addplot {rnd-2};
        \addplot {rnd-3};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]