# Draw multiple arrows from one node to many others using a palette of colors

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors, color

This is a continuation of a previous question: [Draw a set of arrows using a palette of colors](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/480425/152550).

### What I want

I want to **draw multiple arrows starting from one node to more than one. Each arrow that starts in the same node must have the same color; but another node must have the following color (with its arrows of the same color)**, and so on.

You have to achieve the following in the most automatically possible way:

[image: What I want]

### What I have done

This MWE is adapted for a better manipulation of the answer to that question:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\totalnodes{5} % Define the total of nodes-1

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} % From https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/480466/152550
    \foreach \X in {0,...,\totalnodes} {
        \node[circle,draw,name=a\X] at (0,\X) {};
        \node[circle,draw,name=b\X] at (1,\X) {};
        % [actual node] * [0.75 (limits the final color to purple)] * 1/\totalsubjects
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\huenum}{\X*0.75*(1/\totalnodes)}
        \definecolor{mycolor}{hsb}{\huenum,1,1}
        \draw[-latex,mycolor] (a\X) to (b\X);
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: What I have done]

As you can see, I am not able to find an algorithm capable of adding more arrows that come from the same node.

My idea was to make a recursive algorithm that goes through some of the nodes in which I wanted to get the arrow, but I do not know how to jump from node `0` to `2` and then to `5` and so on.

For example, to start with something I tried to change `\draw[-latex,mycolor] (a\X) to (b\X);` to `\draw[-latex,mycolor] (a\X) to (b$\X-0$);` (new line) `\draw[-latex,mycolor] (a\X) to (b$\X-1$);` (new line) `\draw[-latex,mycolor] (a\X) to (b$\X-2$);` etc. but the compiler gives errors (as expected).

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this? You specify the connections in a list. The 0th entry specifies that the 0th a node is to be connected with the b nodes 2 and 3, and so on.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\totalnodes{5} % Define the total of nodes-1

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} % From https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/480466/152550
\def\LstCon{{"{2,3}","{1}","{2}","{2,3,4,5}","{4}","{1,4,5}"}}
    \foreach \X in {0,...,\totalnodes} {
        \node[circle,draw,name=a\X] at (0,\X) {};
        \node[circle,draw,name=b\X] at (1,\X) {};
        }
    \foreach \X in {0,...,\totalnodes} {
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\huenum}{\X*0.75*(1/\totalnodes)}
        \definecolor{mycolor}{hsb}{\huenum,1,1}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\mylst}{\LstCon[\X]}
        \foreach \Y in \mylst       
         {\draw[-latex,mycolor] (a\X) to (b\Y);}
        }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]