# How to connect `pic`s through a set of colorful arrows using `tikzpicture` environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, diagrams, arrows

This is and addendum of a previous question: [How to determine nodes to reduce their length using `tikzpicture` environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/480186/152550), and we need to use this other question: [Draw multiple arrows from one node to many others using a palette of colors](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/480622/152550).

### What I want

**I need to connect two pictures (subjects) using a palette of colors that varies from red to another color.** I am using `tikz`.

Each subject can have more than one outgoing arrow, but each of them must have only one color. However, between subjects the colors vary (according to the number of subjects drawn, if from a total of `n` there are only `n-15` arrows then there will be `n-15` different colors, distributed equally in the palette of chosen colors):

[image: Example]

*(Taken from [marmot's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/480209/152550))*

I want to make  clear that **the arrows should look like these other arrows (but bending)**:

[image: Concept of what I want]

*(Taken from [another marmot's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/480624/152550))*

Each node represents a subject. The code should be as automatic as possible.

### What I have done

I have borrowed the code that [marmot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/121799/marmot) published as an answer of the first attached question and made some changes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0in,footskip=0in,paperwidth=60cm,paperheight=29cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit,calc}
\pgfdeclarelayer{behind}
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{behind,background,main,foreground}
\tikzset{
text field/.style={text height=1.5ex,align=center,rounded corners},
nonfillable title field/.style={text height=2ex,text depth=0.3em,anchor=south,text 
width=5cm,align=center,font=\footnotesize\sffamily},
fillable title field/.style={text height=3.14ex,text depth=0em,anchor=south,text 
width=5cm,align=center,font=\footnotesize\sffamily},
pics/fillable subject/.style={code={%
\node[text field] (-TF) 
{\hspace*{-0.5em}\TextField[align=1,name=#1-day,width=1em,charsize=7pt,maxlen=2,bordercolor={1 1 1}]~~/\hspace*{-0.15em}\TextField[align=1,name=#1-month,width=1em,charsize=7pt,maxlen=2,bordercolor={1 1 1}]~~/\hspace*{-0em}\TextField[align=1,name=#1-year,width=2em,charsize=7pt,maxlen=4,bordercolor={1 1 1}]{}~};
\node[nonfillable title field] (-Title) 
at ([yshift=0.4em]-TF.north) {#1};
\draw[rounded corners] (-TF.south west) |- (-Title.south west)
|- (-Title.north east) -- (-Title.south east) -| (-TF.south east)
 -- cycle;
\draw ([xshift=4pt]-Title.south west) -- ([xshift=-4pt]-Title.south east);
 }},
pics/nonfillable subject/.style={code={%
\node[text field] (-TF) 
{\hspace{1.2em}~/~\hspace{1.15em}~/~\hspace{2.35em}{}};
\node[nonfillable title field] (-Title) 
at ([yshift=0.4em]-TF.north) {#1};
\draw[rounded corners] (-TF.south west) |- (-Title.south west)
|- (-Title.north east) -- (-Title.south east) -| (-TF.south east)
 -- cycle;
\draw ([xshift=4pt]-Title.south west) -- ([xshift=-4pt]-Title.south east);
 }},
pics/fillable elective subject/.style={code={%
\node[text field] (-TF) 
{\hspace*{-0.5em}\TextField[align=1,name=#1-day,width=1em,charsize=7pt,maxlen=2,bordercolor={1 1 1}]~~/\hspace*{-0.15em}\TextField[align=1,name=#1-month,width=1em,charsize=7pt,maxlen=2,bordercolor={1 1 1}]~~/\hspace*{-0em}\TextField[align=1,name=#1-year,width=2em,charsize=7pt,maxlen=4,bordercolor={1 1 1}]{}~};
\node[fillable title field] (-Title) 
at ([yshift=0.4em]-TF.north) {\hspace*{-0.34em}\TextField[align=1,name=#1-electivesubject,width=4.5cm,charsize=8pt,height=.5cm,bordercolor={1 1 1}]{}};
\draw[rounded corners] (-TF.south west) |- (-Title.south west)
|- (-Title.north east) -- (-Title.south east) -| (-TF.south east)
 -- cycle;
\draw ([xshift=4pt]-Title.south west) -- ([xshift=-4pt]-Title.south east);
 }},
pics/nonfillable elective subject/.style={code={%
\node[text field] (-TF) 
{\hspace{1.2em}~/~\hspace{1.15em}~/~\hspace{2.35em}{}};
\node[nonfillable title field] (-Title) 
at ([yshift=0.4em]-TF.north) {};
\draw[rounded corners] (-TF.south west) |- (-Title.south west)
|- (-Title.north east) -- (-Title.south east) -| (-TF.south east)
 -- cycle;
\draw ([xshift=4pt]-Title.south west) -- ([xshift=-4pt]-Title.south east);
 }},
 manoooh/.style={column sep=-1.75cm,row sep=5mm},
 manooohE/.style={column sep=-2.25cm,row sep=5mm,anchor=south},
 electives/.style={column sep=-7.25cm,row sep=5mm},
 fit sep/.initial=4pt,  % change width of node (big rectangle shape)
 fit dist/.initial=40pt, % change node distance (big rectangle shape)
 inlay top sep/.initial=24pt,
 matrix top sep/.initial=24pt,
 manoooh curve/.style={to path={let \p1=($(\tikztotarget)-(\tikztostart)$) 
 in (\tikztostart) .. controls ($(\tikztostart)+(#1*\x1,0)$)
 and ($(\tikztotarget)+(-#1*\x1,0)$) .. (\tikztotarget)}},
 manoooh curve/.default=0.3
}  % From https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/478723/152550

\makeatletter% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/85531/121799
\long\def\ifnodedefined#1#2#3{%
    \@ifundefined{pgf@sh@ns@#1}{#3}{#2}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}   % To suppress page number
\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[white,fill=orange] (0,0) rectangle (\paperwidth,-2cm) node[midway,align=center,font=\Huge] {\bfseries Some text here\\\LARGE More text here};
\end{tikzpicture}

\ifdefined\mymatbottom
\else
\typeout{Please\space recompile\space your\space file!}
\def\mymatbottom{-150pt}
\fi
\ifdefined\myheight
\else
\def\myheight{0}
\typeout{Please\space recompile\space your\space file!}
\fi
\ifdefined\LstMatYShifts
\else
\def\LstMatYShifts{{0pt,0pt,0pt,0pt,0pt,0pt,0pt}}
\fi
\ifdefined\LstMatXShifts
\else
\def\LstMatXShifts{{0pt,0pt,0pt,0pt,0pt,0pt,0pt}}
\fi

%\typeout{height:\myheight}
%\typeout{xshifts(in):\LstMatXShifts}

\vfill
\centering
\begin{Form}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 % step 1: add the matrices, name them mat0, mat1 etc.
 \begin{scope}[local bounding box=matrices] 
  \matrix[manoooh] (mat0) at ({\LstMatXShifts[0]},{\LstMatYShifts[0]}) {
         \pic[local bounding box=A] (0) {nonfillable subject={Subject A}};  \\
         \pic (1) {nonfillable subject={Subject B}};  \\
  };
  \matrix[manoooh] (mat1) at ({\LstMatXShifts[1]},{\LstMatYShifts[1]}) {

         \pic (2) {nonfillable subject={Subject C}};  \\
         \pic (3) {nonfillable subject={Subject D}};  \\
         \pic (4) {nonfillable subject={Subject E}};  \\
         \pic (5) {nonfillable subject={Subject F}};  \\
         \pic (6) {nonfillable subject={Subject G}};  \\
         \pic (7) {nonfillable subject={Subject H}};  \\
         \pic (8) {nonfillable subject={Subject I}};  \\
         \pic[draw=red] (9) {nonfillable subject={Subject J}};  \\
    };
  \matrix[manoooh] (mat2) at ({\LstMatXShifts[2]},{\LstMatYShifts[2]}) {
         \pic[draw=red] (10) {nonfillable subject={Subject K}};  \\
         \pic (11) {nonfillable subject={Subject L}};  \\
         \pic (12) {nonfillable subject={Subject A}};  \\
         \pic (13) {nonfillable subject={Subject N}};  \\
         \pic (14) {nonfillable subject={Subject O}};  \\
         \pic (15) {nonfillable subject={Subject P}};  \\
         \pic (16) {nonfillable subject={Subject Q}};  \\
         \pic (17) {nonfillable subject={Subject R}};  \\
    };  
  \matrix[manoooh] (mat3) at ({\LstMatXShifts[3]},{\LstMatYShifts[3]}) {
         \pic[draw=red] (18) {nonfillable subject={Subject S}};  \\
         \pic (19) {nonfillable subject={Subject T}};  \\
         \pic (20) {nonfillable subject={Subject U}};  \\
         \pic (21) {nonfillable subject={Subject V}};  \\
         \pic (22) {nonfillable subject={Subject W}};  \\
         \pic (23) {nonfillable subject={Subject X}};  \\
         \pic (24) {nonfillable subject={Subject Y}};  \\
         \pic (25) {nonfillable subject={Subject Z}};  \\
    };
  \matrix[manooohE] (matE3) at ({\LstMatXShifts[3]},\mymatbottom) {
        \pic (L3E1) {nonfillable elective subject={Subject}}; & &
        \pic (L3E2) {nonfillable elective subject={Subject}}; \\
        & \pic (L3E3) {nonfillable elective subject={Subject}};  & \\
    };
    \matrix[manoooh] (mat4) at ({\LstMatXShifts[4]},{\LstMatYShifts[4]}) {
        & \pic[draw=red] (26) {nonfillable subject={Subject AA}}; & \\
        \pic (27) {nonfillable subject={Subject AB}}; & & \pic (28) {nonfillable subject={Subject AC}}; \\
        & \pic (29) {nonfillable subject={Subject AD}}; & \\
        & \pic (30) {nonfillable subject={Subject AE}}; & \\
        & \pic (31) {nonfillable subject={Subject AF}}; & \\
        & \pic (32) {nonfillable subject={Subject AG}}; & \\
    };
    \matrix[manooohE] (matE4) at ({\LstMatXShifts[4]},\mymatbottom) {
        \pic (L4E1) {nonfillable elective subject={Subject}}; \\
    };
    \matrix[manoooh] (mat5) at ({\LstMatXShifts[5]},{\LstMatYShifts[5]}) {
         \pic (33) {nonfillable subject={Subject AH}};  \\
         \pic (34) {nonfillable subject={Subject AI}};  \\
         \pic[draw=red] (35) {nonfillable subject={Subject AJ}};  \\
         \pic (36) {nonfillable subject={Subject AK}};  \\
    };
    \matrix[manooohE] (matE5) at ({\LstMatXShifts[5]},\mymatbottom) {
         \pic (L5E1) {nonfillable elective subject={Subject}};  \\
         \pic (L5E2) {nonfillable elective subject={Subject}};  \\
         \pic (L5E3) {nonfillable elective subject={Subject}};  \\
         \pic (L5E4) {nonfillable elective subject={Subject}};  \\
         \pic (L5E5) {nonfillable elective subject={Subject}};  \\
    };
 \end{scope}
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\groupwidth}{0}
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\lastwidth}{0}
 \foreach \X in {0,...,5} %<- if you have more or less matrices, adjust 3       
 {
  \node[anchor=south,yshift=1cm,align=center,font=\LARGE\bfseries\boldmath] 
  at (mat\X |-matrices.north) (L\X) {Level $\X$}; 
  \ifnodedefined{matE\X}{% has inlay
   \node[xshift=1em,anchor=south west,font=\LARGE\bfseries,opacity=0] (matEl\X) at (matE\X.north west) {Electives};
   \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
   \path let \p1=($(mat\X.north east)-(mat\X.south west)$) in
   node[fit=(matE\X) (matEl\X),inner ysep=5mm,fill=blue!30,rounded
   corners=40pt,minimum width=\x1-2*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/fit sep},
   inner xsep=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/fit sep}](F\X){};
   \node[xshift=1em,anchor=south west,font=\LARGE\bfseries] 
   (matEl\X) at ([xshift=1.3em]F\X.west|-matEl\X.center) {Electives};
   \end{pgfonlayer}
   \path let \p1=($(mat\X.north east)-(mat\X.south west)$),
    \p2=($(F\X.north east)-(F\X.south west)$),
    \n1={max(abs(\y1)/2+abs(\y2)/2+0*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/inlay top sep},\mymatbottom)}
      in 
    \pgfextra{\xdef\mymatbottom{\n1}
       \ifnum\X=0
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\groupwidth}{0}
       \else    
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\groupwidth}{\groupwidth+max(\x1,\x2)/2+\lastwidth/2+2*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/fit sep}+\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/fit dist}}
       \fi
       \pgfmathsetmacro{\lastwidth}{max(\x1,\x2)+8*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/fit sep}}
       \xdef\lastwidth{\lastwidth}
       \xdef\groupwidth{\groupwidth}     
       \pgfmathsetmacro{\myheight}{max(\y1+\y2+%
         \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/inlay top sep}+\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/matrix top sep},%
         \myheight)}
       \xdef\myheight{\myheight}
       \pgfmathsetmacro{\myshift}{(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/inlay top sep}+\y2)/2}
       \ifnum\X=0
       \xdef\LstMatYShifts{\myshift pt}
       \xdef\LstMatXShifts{0pt}
       \else
       \xdef\LstMatYShifts{\LstMatYShifts,\myshift pt}
       \xdef\LstMatXShifts{\LstMatXShifts,\groupwidth pt}
       \fi};    
   % the fit parameters determine the shape of the background rectangles
   \begin{pgfonlayer}{behind}
   \node[fit=(L\X) (mat\X) (matrices.south-|mat\X.south)
   (matE\X) (matEl\X),inner ysep=8mm,inner xsep=4*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/fit sep},
   fill=orange!30,rounded corners=50pt](F\X){};
   \end{pgfonlayer}}{% no inlay
   \path 
    let \p1=($(mat\X.north east)-(mat\X.south west)$),
     \n1={max(abs(\y1)/2,\mymatbottom)}
      in 
     \pgfextra{\xdef\mymatbottom{\n1}
       \ifnum\X=0
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\groupwidth}{0}
       \else    
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\groupwidth}{\groupwidth+\x1/2+\lastwidth/2+\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/fit dist}}
       \fi
       \xdef\groupwidth{\groupwidth}
       \xdef\lastwidth{\x1}
       \pgfmathsetmacro{\myheight}{max(\y1+\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/matrix top sep},\myheight)} 
       \xdef\myheight{\myheight}
       \ifnum\X=0
       \xdef\LstMatYShifts{0pt}
       \xdef\LstMatXShifts{0pt}
       \else
       \xdef\LstMatYShifts{\LstMatYShifts,0pt}
       \xdef\LstMatXShifts{\LstMatXShifts,\groupwidth pt}
       \fi};   
   % the fit parameters determine the shape of the background rectangles
   \begin{pgfonlayer}{behind}
   \node[fit=(L\X) (mat\X) (matrices.south-|mat\X.south),inner ysep=8mm,
   fill=orange!30,rounded corners=50pt](F\X){};
   \end{pgfonlayer}
   }
  }
 \makeatletter
 \immediate\write\@mainaux{\xdef\string\mymatbottom{-\mymatbottom}\relax}
 \immediate\write\@mainaux{\xdef\string\myheight{\myheight}\relax}
 \immediate\write\@mainaux{\xdef\string\LstMatYShifts{{\LstMatYShifts}}\relax}
 \immediate\write\@mainaux{\xdef\string\LstMatXShifts{{\LstMatXShifts}}\relax}
 \makeatother

    %% FROM HERE START THE PROBLEMS:

    \newcommand\totalnodes{5} % Define the total of subjects that need arrows-1

    % From https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/480624/152550

    % now add the arrows.

    \def\LstCon{%
        {
        "{2,...,9}",%subjects that 0 links
        "{2,10,13,14}",%subjects that 1 links
        "{11,14}",%subjects that 2 links
        "{10,13,14,25}",%subjects that 3 links
        "{36}",%subjects that 8 links <- Will it be possible to use/Should we use 'manoooh curve'?
        }
    }
    \foreach \X in {0,...,\totalnodes} {
        \pic (\X) {nonfillable subject={I dont know what to write here}};
    }
    \foreach \X in {0,...,\totalnodes} {
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\huenum}{\X*0.75*(1/\totalnodes)}
        \definecolor{mycolor}{hsb}{\huenum,1,1}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\mylst}{\LstCon[\X]}
        \foreach \Y in \mylst {
            %\draw[-latex,mycolor,very thick] (a\X) to (b\Y);
            \draw[-latex,mycolor,very thick] (0-Title) to[out=0,in=180] (\Y-Title);% Draws arrows from subject 0 to "{2,...,9}". It does not work
            % etc...
        }
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{Form}

\vfill

\end{document}
```

[image: What I have done]

**Please pay attention to the last lines (from #261 to #290).**

**Changes:**

- Renamed every subject by a numerical value (`(0)`, `(1)` etc.).
- Changed the meaning of `node` to `subject` in the definitions and comments to be more descriptive.
- The list of subjects to relate is already made (there are 5 lines because they are 5 subjects with arrows).
- Deleted the (old) way of drawing arrows.
- Deleted the long arrow style, called `manoooh curve`.

**Problems:**

- When I compile the source code I get a `pic` that has drawn all the outgoing arrows. Arrows of different colors must go to their respective subjects.
- I get the error "Dimension too large" because of the long blue arrow.
- [marmot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/121799/marmot) fixed the previous issue by creating a new type of curve: `manoooh curve`, which is necessary to get rid of the error. However, I am not able to put both designs within the same loop since I do not know how that will affect the color of that arrow.
- If you find any improvement that you think may be better for the visual design, go ahead!

How can we implement an algorithm that can solve these problems?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not understand why you are redrawing the nodes rather than connecting existing ones. All I did was just to change this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0in,footskip=0in,paperwidth=60cm,paperheight=29cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit,calc}
\pgfdeclarelayer{behind}
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{behind,background,main,foreground}
\tikzset{
text field/.style={text height=1.5ex,align=center,rounded corners},
nonfillable title field/.style={text height=2ex,text depth=0.3em,anchor=south,text 
width=5cm,align=center,font=\footnotesize\sffamily},
fillable title field/.style={text height=3.14ex,text depth=0em,anchor=south,text 
width=5cm,align=center,font=\footnotesize\sffamily},
pics/fillable subject/.style={code={%
\node[text field] (-TF) 
{\hspace*{-0.5em}\TextField[align=1,name=#1-day,width=1em,charsize=7pt,maxlen=2,bordercolor={1 1 1}]~~/\hspace*{-0.15em}\TextField[align=1,name=#1-month,width=1em,charsize=7pt,maxlen=2,bordercolor={1 1 1}]~~/\hspace*{-0em}\TextField[align=1,name=#1-year,width=2em,charsize=7pt,maxlen=4,bordercolor={1 1 1}]{}~};
\node[nonfillable title field] (-Title) 
at ([yshift=0.4em]-TF.north) {#1};
\draw[rounded corners] (-TF.south west) |- (-Title.south west)
|- (-Title.north east) -- (-Title.south east) -| (-TF.south east)
 -- cycle;
\draw ([xshift=4pt]-Title.south west) -- ([xshift=-4pt]-Title.south east);
 }},
pics/nonfillable subject/.style={code={%
\node[text field] (-TF) 
{\hspace{1.2em}~/~\hspace{1.15em}~/~\hspace{2.35em}{}};
\node[nonfillable title field] (-Title) 
at ([yshift=0.4em]-TF.north) {#1};
\draw[rounded corners] (-TF.south west) |- (-Title.south west)
|- (-Title.north east) -- (-Title.south east) -| (-TF.south east)
 -- cycle;
\draw ([xshift=4pt]-Title.south west) -- ([xshift=-4pt]-Title.south east);
 }},
pics/fillable elective subject/.style={code={%
\node[text field] (-TF) 
{\hspace*{-0.5em}\TextField[align=1,name=#1-day,width=1em,charsize=7pt,maxlen=2,bordercolor={1 1 1}]~~/\hspace*{-0.15em}\TextField[align=1,name=#1-month,width=1em,charsize=7pt,maxlen=2,bordercolor={1 1 1}]~~/\hspace*{-0em}\TextField[align=1,name=#1-year,width=2em,charsize=7pt,maxlen=4,bordercolor={1 1 1}]{}~};
\node[fillable title field] (-Title) 
at ([yshift=0.4em]-TF.north) {\hspace*{-0.34em}\TextField[align=1,name=#1-electivesubject,width=4.5cm,charsize=8pt,height=.5cm,bordercolor={1 1 1}]{}};
\draw[rounded corners] (-TF.south west) |- (-Title.south west)
|- (-Title.north east) -- (-Title.south east) -| (-TF.south east)
 -- cycle;
\draw ([xshift=4pt]-Title.south west) -- ([xshift=-4pt]-Title.south east);
 }},
pics/nonfillable elective subject/.style={code={%
\node[text field] (-TF) 
{\hspace{1.2em}~/~\hspace{1.15em}~/~\hspace{2.35em}{}};
\node[nonfillable title field] (-Title) 
at ([yshift=0.4em]-TF.north) {};
\draw[rounded corners] (-TF.south west) |- (-Title.south west)
|- (-Title.north east) -- (-Title.south east) -| (-TF.south east)
 -- cycle;
\draw ([xshift=4pt]-Title.south west) -- ([xshift=-4pt]-Title.south east);
 }},
 manoooh/.style={column sep=-1.75cm,row sep=5mm},
 manooohE/.style={column sep=-2.25cm,row sep=5mm,anchor=south},
 electives/.style={column sep=-7.25cm,row sep=5mm},
 fit sep/.initial=4pt,  % change width of node (big rectangle shape)
 fit dist/.initial=40pt, % change node distance (big rectangle shape)
 inlay top sep/.initial=24pt,
 matrix top sep/.initial=24pt,
 manoooh curve/.style={to path={let \p1=($(\tikztotarget)-(\tikztostart)$) 
 in (\tikztostart) .. controls ($(\tikztostart)+(#1*\x1,0)$)
 and ($(\tikztotarget)+(-#1*\x1,0)$) .. (\tikztotarget)}},
 manoooh curve/.default=0.3
}  % From https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/478723/152550

\makeatletter% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/85531/121799
\long\def\ifnodedefined#1#2#3{%
    \@ifundefined{pgf@sh@ns@#1}{#3}{#2}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}   % To suppress page number
\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[white,fill=orange] (0,0) rectangle (\paperwidth,-2cm) node[midway,align=center,font=\Huge] {\bfseries Some text here\\\LARGE More text here};
\end{tikzpicture}

\ifdefined\mymatbottom
\else
\typeout{Please\space recompile\space your\space file!}
\def\mymatbottom{-150pt}
\fi
\ifdefined\myheight
\else
\def\myheight{0}
\typeout{Please\space recompile\space your\space file!}
\fi
\ifdefined\LstMatYShifts
\else
\def\LstMatYShifts{{0pt,0pt,0pt,0pt,0pt,0pt,0pt}}
\fi
\ifdefined\LstMatXShifts
\else
\def\LstMatXShifts{{0pt,0pt,0pt,0pt,0pt,0pt,0pt}}
\fi

%\typeout{height:\myheight}
%\typeout{xshifts(in):\LstMatXShifts}

\vfill
\centering
\begin{Form}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 % step 1: add the matrices, name them mat0, mat1 etc.
 \begin{scope}[local bounding box=matrices] 
  \matrix[manoooh] (mat0) at ({\LstMatXShifts[0]},{\LstMatYShifts[0]}) {
         \pic[local bounding box=A] (0) {nonfillable subject={Subject A}};  \\
         \pic (1) {nonfillable subject={Subject B}};  \\
  };
  \matrix[manoooh] (mat1) at ({\LstMatXShifts[1]},{\LstMatYShifts[1]}) {

         \pic (2) {nonfillable subject={Subject C}};  \\
         \pic (3) {nonfillable subject={Subject D}};  \\
         \pic (4) {nonfillable subject={Subject E}};  \\
         \pic (5) {nonfillable subject={Subject F}};  \\
         \pic (6) {nonfillable subject={Subject G}};  \\
         \pic (7) {nonfillable subject={Subject H}};  \\
         \pic (8) {nonfillable subject={Subject I}};  \\
         \pic[draw=red] (9) {nonfillable subject={Subject J}};  \\
    };
  \matrix[manoooh] (mat2) at ({\LstMatXShifts[2]},{\LstMatYShifts[2]}) {
         \pic[draw=red] (10) {nonfillable subject={Subject K}};  \\
         \pic (11) {nonfillable subject={Subject L}};  \\
         \pic (12) {nonfillable subject={Subject A}};  \\
         \pic (13) {nonfillable subject={Subject N}};  \\
         \pic (14) {nonfillable subject={Subject O}};  \\
         \pic (15) {nonfillable subject={Subject P}};  \\
         \pic (16) {nonfillable subject={Subject Q}};  \\
         \pic (17) {nonfillable subject={Subject R}};  \\
    };  
  \matrix[manoooh] (mat3) at ({\LstMatXShifts[3]},{\LstMatYShifts[3]}) {
         \pic[draw=red] (18) {nonfillable subject={Subject S}};  \\
         \pic (19) {nonfillable subject={Subject T}};  \\
         \pic (20) {nonfillable subject={Subject U}};  \\
         \pic (21) {nonfillable subject={Subject V}};  \\
         \pic (22) {nonfillable subject={Subject W}};  \\
         \pic (23) {nonfillable subject={Subject X}};  \\
         \pic (24) {nonfillable subject={Subject Y}};  \\
         \pic (25) {nonfillable subject={Subject Z}};  \\
    };
  \matrix[manooohE] (matE3) at ({\LstMatXShifts[3]},\mymatbottom) {
        \pic (L3E1) {nonfillable elective subject={Subject}}; & &
        \pic (L3E2) {nonfillable elective subject={Subject}}; \\
        & \pic (L3E3) {nonfillable elective subject={Subject}};  & \\
    };
    \matrix[manoooh] (mat4) at ({\LstMatXShifts[4]},{\LstMatYShifts[4]}) {
        & \pic[draw=red] (26) {nonfillable subject={Subject AA}}; & \\
        \pic (27) {nonfillable subject={Subject AB}}; & & \pic (28) {nonfillable subject={Subject AC}}; \\
        & \pic (29) {nonfillable subject={Subject AD}}; & \\
        & \pic (30) {nonfillable subject={Subject AE}}; & \\
        & \pic (31) {nonfillable subject={Subject AF}}; & \\
        & \pic (32) {nonfillable subject={Subject AG}}; & \\
    };
    \matrix[manooohE] (matE4) at ({\LstMatXShifts[4]},\mymatbottom) {
        \pic (L4E1) {nonfillable elective subject={Subject}}; \\
    };
    \matrix[manoooh] (mat5) at ({\LstMatXShifts[5]},{\LstMatYShifts[5]}) {
         \pic (33) {nonfillable subject={Subject AH}};  \\
         \pic (34) {nonfillable subject={Subject AI}};  \\
         \pic[draw=red] (35) {nonfillable subject={Subject AJ}};  \\
         \pic (36) {nonfillable subject={Subject AK}};  \\
    };
    \matrix[manooohE] (matE5) at ({\LstMatXShifts[5]},\mymatbottom) {
         \pic (L5E1) {nonfillable elective subject={Subject}};  \\
         \pic (L5E2) {nonfillable elective subject={Subject}};  \\
         \pic (L5E3) {nonfillable elective subject={Subject}};  \\
         \pic (L5E4) {nonfillable elective subject={Subject}};  \\
         \pic (L5E5) {nonfillable elective subject={Subject}};  \\
    };
 \end{scope}
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\groupwidth}{0}
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\lastwidth}{0}
 \foreach \X in {0,...,5} %<- if you have more or less matrices, adjust 3       
 {
  \node[anchor=south,yshift=1cm,align=center,font=\LARGE\bfseries\boldmath] 
  at (mat\X |-matrices.north) (L\X) {Level $\X$}; 
  \ifnodedefined{matE\X}{% has inlay
   \node[xshift=1em,anchor=south west,font=\LARGE\bfseries,opacity=0] (matEl\X) at (matE\X.north west) {Electives};
   \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
   \path let \p1=($(mat\X.north east)-(mat\X.south west)$) in
   node[fit=(matE\X) (matEl\X),inner ysep=5mm,fill=blue!30,rounded
   corners=40pt,minimum width=\x1-2*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/fit sep},
   inner xsep=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/fit sep}](F\X){};
   \node[xshift=1em,anchor=south west,font=\LARGE\bfseries] 
   (matEl\X) at ([xshift=1.3em]F\X.west|-matEl\X.center) {Electives};
   \end{pgfonlayer}
   \path let \p1=($(mat\X.north east)-(mat\X.south west)$),
    \p2=($(F\X.north east)-(F\X.south west)$),
    \n1={max(abs(\y1)/2+abs(\y2)/2+0*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/inlay top sep},\mymatbottom)}
      in 
    \pgfextra{\xdef\mymatbottom{\n1}
       \ifnum\X=0
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\groupwidth}{0}
       \else    
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\groupwidth}{\groupwidth+max(\x1,\x2)/2+\lastwidth/2+2*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/fit sep}+\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/fit dist}}
       \fi
       \pgfmathsetmacro{\lastwidth}{max(\x1,\x2)+8*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/fit sep}}
       \xdef\lastwidth{\lastwidth}
       \xdef\groupwidth{\groupwidth}     
       \pgfmathsetmacro{\myheight}{max(\y1+\y2+%
         \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/inlay top sep}+\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/matrix top sep},%
         \myheight)}
       \xdef\myheight{\myheight}
       \pgfmathsetmacro{\myshift}{(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/inlay top sep}+\y2)/2}
       \ifnum\X=0
       \xdef\LstMatYShifts{\myshift pt}
       \xdef\LstMatXShifts{0pt}
       \else
       \xdef\LstMatYShifts{\LstMatYShifts,\myshift pt}
       \xdef\LstMatXShifts{\LstMatXShifts,\groupwidth pt}
       \fi};    
   % the fit parameters determine the shape of the background rectangles
   \begin{pgfonlayer}{behind}
   \node[fit=(L\X) (mat\X) (matrices.south-|mat\X.south)
   (matE\X) (matEl\X),inner ysep=8mm,inner xsep=4*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/fit sep},
   fill=orange!30,rounded corners=50pt](F\X){};
   \end{pgfonlayer}}{% no inlay
   \path 
    let \p1=($(mat\X.north east)-(mat\X.south west)$),
     \n1={max(abs(\y1)/2,\mymatbottom)}
      in 
     \pgfextra{\xdef\mymatbottom{\n1}
       \ifnum\X=0
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\groupwidth}{0}
       \else    
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\groupwidth}{\groupwidth+\x1/2+\lastwidth/2+\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/fit dist}}
       \fi
       \xdef\groupwidth{\groupwidth}
       \xdef\lastwidth{\x1}
       \pgfmathsetmacro{\myheight}{max(\y1+\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/matrix top sep},\myheight)} 
       \xdef\myheight{\myheight}
       \ifnum\X=0
       \xdef\LstMatYShifts{0pt}
       \xdef\LstMatXShifts{0pt}
       \else
       \xdef\LstMatYShifts{\LstMatYShifts,0pt}
       \xdef\LstMatXShifts{\LstMatXShifts,\groupwidth pt}
       \fi};   
   % the fit parameters determine the shape of the background rectangles
   \begin{pgfonlayer}{behind}
   \node[fit=(L\X) (mat\X) (matrices.south-|mat\X.south),inner ysep=8mm,
   fill=orange!30,rounded corners=50pt](F\X){};
   \end{pgfonlayer}
   }
  }
 \makeatletter
 \immediate\write\@mainaux{\xdef\string\mymatbottom{-\mymatbottom}\relax}
 \immediate\write\@mainaux{\xdef\string\myheight{\myheight}\relax}
 \immediate\write\@mainaux{\xdef\string\LstMatYShifts{{\LstMatYShifts}}\relax}
 \immediate\write\@mainaux{\xdef\string\LstMatXShifts{{\LstMatXShifts}}\relax}
 \makeatother

    %% FROM HERE START THE PROBLEMS:

    \newcommand\totalnodes{5} % Define the total of subjects that need arrows-1

    % From https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/480624/152550

    % now add the arrows.

    \def\LstCon{%
        {
        "{2,...,9}",%subjects that 0 links
        "{2,10,13,14}",%subjects that 1 links
        "{11,14}",%subjects that 2 links
        "{10,13,14,25}",%subjects that 3 links
        "{36}",%subjects that 8 links <- Will it be possible to use/Should we use 'manoooh curve'?
        }
    }
    \foreach \X in {0,...,\totalnodes} {
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\huenum}{\X*0.75*(1/\totalnodes)}
        \definecolor{mycolor}{hsb}{\huenum,1,1}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\mylst}{\LstCon[\X]}
        \foreach \Y in \mylst {
            %\draw[-latex,mycolor,very thick] (a\X) to (b\Y);
            \draw[-latex,mycolor,very thick] (\X-Title.east) 
            to[manoooh curve] (\Y-Title.west);% Draws arrows from subject 0 to "{2,...,9}". It does not work
            % etc...
        }
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{Form}

\vfill

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @manooooh My bad. I was using `edge` where I should have used `to`.