# How to put a box and use columns to separate arrows

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment, arrows, multicolumn

I am using the following resources:

- The `multicols` environment of [Draw a set of arrows using a palette of colors](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/480466/152550).
- The box of [How to put a long piece of text in a box?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25904/152550)

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0in,footskip=0in]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[tikz]{ocgx2}
\usepackage{amssymb} % \checkmark 
% check box command for layer switching     
\newcommand\layerCheckBox[3]{% 
  % #1: switch id, if empty use #2 instead 
  % #2: layer ids to be toggled (space separated if multiple ids), 
  % #3: initial visibility 
  \resizebox{2ex}{!}{\ooalign{% 
    \switchocg{#1 #2}{$\square$}\cr% 
    \begin{ocg}{% 
      \ifx\nil#1\nil#2\else#1\fi% 
    }{% 
      \ifx\nil#1\nil#2\else#1\fi% 
    }{#3}$\checkmark$\end{ocg}% 
  }}% 
} 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 

\usepackage{tikz}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand\totalnodes{4} % Define the total of subjects that need arrows-1
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\flushleft
\qquad\parbox{0.4\linewidth}{\hypersetup{pdfborder={0 0 0}}%
    % list of OCGs, space separated
    \def\ocglist{}%
    \foreach \X in {0,...,\totalnodes} {\xdef\ocglist{\ocglist\space myArrow\X}}
    \fbox{%
    \parbox{5cm}{%
            % on/off All
            \showocg{\ocglist}{\fboxsep=1pt\fbox{\rule{0pt}{1.7ex}on}}/%
            \hideocg{\ocglist}{\fboxsep=1pt\fbox{\rule{0pt}{1.7ex}off}} All\\%
            % checkboxes
            \foreach \X in {0,...,\totalnodes} {%
                \begin{multicols}{4}
                    \layerCheckBox{}{myArrow\X}{on}\begin{tikzpicture}%
                        \pgfmathsetmacro{\huenum}{\X*0.75*(1/\totalnodes)}\definecolor{mycolor}{hsb}{\huenum,1,1}\draw[-latex,mycolor,very thick] (0,0) -- (1,0);%
                    \end{tikzpicture}\\%
                \end{multicols}
            }%
        }
    }
}

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

I would like to:

1. Center every arrow to the corresponding checkbox.
2. Put to work `multicols` (it says "4" but it is actually 1 column).
3. Get rid of the "Bad Box(es)" messages by making a good use of `fbox` (or similar command).
4. Not say `\parbox{5cm}{...}` but `\parbox{<automatic>}{...}`, where `parbox` calculates the proper vertical space of the box, based on the quantity of columns.

I want this:

[image: What I want]

P.S. There can actually be 4 or 5 or any number of columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I didn't screw it but I tested on acroread and it seemed to still work. All I did was to comment out `multicolumn` (the purpose of which I didn't understand), added some `\quad`s and gave the `tikzpicture`s some baselines.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0in,footskip=0in,paperwidth=60cm,paperheight=32cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[tikz]{ocgx2}
\usepackage{amssymb} % \checkmark 
% check box command for layer switching     
\newcommand\layerCheckBox[3]{% 
  % #1: switch id, if empty use #2 instead 
  % #2: layer ids to be toggled (space separated if multiple ids), 
  % #3: initial visibility 
  \resizebox{2ex}{!}{\ooalign{% 
    \switchocg{#1 #2}{$\square$}\cr% 
    \begin{ocg}{% 
      \ifx\nil#1\nil#2\else#1\fi% 
    }{% 
      \ifx\nil#1\nil#2\else#1\fi% 
    }{#3}$\checkmark$\end{ocg}% 
  }}% 
} 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% 

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit,calc}
\pgfdeclarelayer{behind}
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{behind,background,main,foreground}
\tikzset{
text field/.style={text height=1.5ex,align=center,rounded corners},
nonfillable title field/.style={text height=2ex,text depth=0.3em,anchor=south,text 
width=5cm,align=center,font=\footnotesize\sffamily},
fillable title field/.style={text height=3.14ex,text depth=0em,anchor=south,text 
width=5cm,align=center,font=\footnotesize\sffamily},
pics/fillable subject/.style={code={%
\node[text field] (-TF) 
{\hspace*{-0.5em}\TextField[align=1,name=#1-day,width=1em,charsize=7pt,maxlen=2,bordercolor={1 1 1}]~~/\hspace*{-0.15em}\TextField[align=1,name=#1-month,width=1em,charsize=7pt,maxlen=2,bordercolor={1 1 1}]~~/\hspace*{-0em}\TextField[align=1,name=#1-year,width=2em,charsize=7pt,maxlen=4,bordercolor={1 1 1}]{}~};
\node[nonfillable title field] (-Title) 
at ([yshift=0.4em]-TF.north) {#1};
\draw[rounded corners] (-TF.south west) |- (-Title.south west)
|- (-Title.north east) -- (-Title.south east) -| (-TF.south east)
 -- cycle;
\draw ([xshift=4pt]-Title.south west) -- ([xshift=-4pt]-Title.south east);
 }},
pics/nonfillable subject/.style={code={%
\node[text field] (-TF) 
{\hspace{1.2em}~/~\hspace{1.15em}~/~\hspace{2.35em}{}};
\node[nonfillable title field] (-Title) 
at ([yshift=0.4em]-TF.north) {#1};
\draw[rounded corners] (-TF.south west) |- (-Title.south west)
|- (-Title.north east) -- (-Title.south east) -| (-TF.south east)
 -- cycle;
\draw ([xshift=4pt]-Title.south west) -- ([xshift=-4pt]-Title.south east);
 }},
pics/fillable elective subject/.style={code={%
\node[text field] (-TF) 
{\hspace*{-0.5em}\TextField[align=1,name=#1-day,width=1em,charsize=7pt,maxlen=2,bordercolor={1 1 1}]~~/\hspace*{-0.15em}\TextField[align=1,name=#1-month,width=1em,charsize=7pt,maxlen=2,bordercolor={1 1 1}]~~/\hspace*{-0em}\TextField[align=1,name=#1-year,width=2em,charsize=7pt,maxlen=4,bordercolor={1 1 1}]{}~};
\node[fillable title field] (-Title) 
at ([yshift=0.4em]-TF.north) {\hspace*{-0.34em}\TextField[align=1,name=#1-electivesubject,width=4.5cm,charsize=8pt,height=.5cm,bordercolor={1 1 1}]{}};
\draw[rounded corners] (-TF.south west) |- (-Title.south west)
|- (-Title.north east) -- (-Title.south east) -| (-TF.south east)
 -- cycle;
\draw ([xshift=4pt]-Title.south west) -- ([xshift=-4pt]-Title.south east);
 }},
pics/nonfillable elective subject/.style={code={%
\node[text field] (-TF) 
{\hspace{1.2em}~/~\hspace{1.15em}~/~\hspace{2.35em}{}};
\node[nonfillable title field] (-Title) 
at ([yshift=0.4em]-TF.north) {};
\draw[rounded corners] (-TF.south west) |- (-Title.south west)
|- (-Title.north east) -- (-Title.south east) -| (-TF.south east)
 -- cycle;
\draw ([xshift=4pt]-Title.south west) -- ([xshift=-4pt]-Title.south east);
 }},
 manoooh/.style={column sep=-1.75cm,row sep=5mm},
 manooohE/.style={column sep=-2.25cm,row sep=5mm,anchor=south},
 electives/.style={column sep=-7.25cm,row sep=5mm},
 fit sep/.initial=4pt,  % change width of node (big rectangle shape)
 fit dist/.initial=40pt, % change node distance (big rectangle shape)
 inlay top sep/.initial=24pt,
 matrix top sep/.initial=24pt,
 manoooh curve/.style={to path={let \p1=($(\tikztotarget)-(\tikztostart)$) 
 in (\tikztostart) .. controls ($(\tikztostart)+(#1*\x1,0)$)
 and ($(\tikztotarget)+(-#1*\x1,0)$) .. (\tikztotarget)}},
 manoooh curve/.default=0.3,
 along node/.style={insert path={
 to[out=0,in=180]
    ([yshift=5pt]#1-Title.north west) -- ([yshift=5pt]#1-Title.north east)}}
}  % From https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/478723/152550

\makeatletter% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/85531/121799
\long\def\ifnodedefined#1#2#3{%
    \@ifundefined{pgf@sh@ns@#1}{#3}{#2}%
}
\makeatother

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand\totalnodes{4} % Define the total of subjects that need arrows-1
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}   % To suppress page number
\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[white,fill=orange] (0,0) rectangle (\paperwidth,-2cm) node[midway,align=center,font=\Huge] {\bfseries Some text here\\\LARGE More text here};
\end{tikzpicture}

\ifdefined\mymatbottom
\else
\typeout{Please\space recompile\space your\space file!}
\def\mymatbottom{-150pt}
\fi
\ifdefined\myheight
\else
\def\myheight{0}
\typeout{Please\space recompile\space your\space file!}
\fi
\ifdefined\LstMatYShifts
\else
\def\LstMatYShifts{{0pt,0pt,0pt,0pt,0pt,0pt,0pt}}
\fi
\ifdefined\LstMatXShifts
\else
\def\LstMatXShifts{{0pt,0pt,0pt,0pt,0pt,0pt,0pt}}
\fi

%\typeout{height:\myheight}
%\typeout{xshifts(in):\LstMatXShifts}

\vfill
\centering
\begin{Form}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 % step 1: add the matrices, name them mat0, mat1 etc.
 \begin{scope}[local bounding box=matrices] 
  \matrix[manoooh] (mat0) at ({\LstMatXShifts[0]},{\LstMatYShifts[0]}) {
         \pic[local bounding box=A] (0) {nonfillable subject={Subject A}};  \\
         \pic (1) {nonfillable subject={Subject B}};  \\
  };
  \matrix[manoooh] (mat1) at ({\LstMatXShifts[1]},{\LstMatYShifts[1]}) {

         \pic (2) {nonfillable subject={Subject C}};  \\
         \pic (3) {nonfillable subject={Subject D}};  \\
         \pic (4) {nonfillable subject={Subject E}};  \\
         \pic (5) {nonfillable subject={Subject F}};  \\
         \pic (6) {nonfillable subject={Subject G}};  \\
         \pic (7) {nonfillable subject={Subject H}};  \\
         \pic (8) {nonfillable subject={Subject I}};  \\
         \pic[draw=red] (9) {nonfillable subject={Subject J}};  \\
    };
  \matrix[manoooh] (mat2) at ({\LstMatXShifts[2]},{\LstMatYShifts[2]}) {
         \pic[draw=red] (10) {nonfillable subject={Subject K}};  \\
         \pic (11) {nonfillable subject={Subject L}};  \\
         \pic (12) {nonfillable subject={Subject A}};  \\
         \pic (13) {nonfillable subject={Subject N}};  \\
         \pic (14) {nonfillable subject={Subject O}};  \\
         \pic (15) {nonfillable subject={Subject P}};  \\
         \pic (16) {nonfillable subject={Subject Q}};  \\
         \pic (17) {nonfillable subject={Subject R}};  \\
    };  
  \matrix[manoooh] (mat3) at ({\LstMatXShifts[3]},{\LstMatYShifts[3]}) {
         \pic[draw=red] (18) {nonfillable subject={Subject S}};  \\
         \pic (19) {nonfillable subject={Subject T}};  \\
         \pic (20) {nonfillable subject={Subject U}};  \\
         \pic (21) {nonfillable subject={Subject V}};  \\
         \pic (22) {nonfillable subject={Subject W}};  \\
         \pic (23) {nonfillable subject={Subject X}};  \\
         \pic (24) {nonfillable subject={Subject Y}};  \\
         \pic (25) {nonfillable subject={Subject Z}};  \\
    };
  \matrix[manooohE] (matE3) at ({\LstMatXShifts[3]},\mymatbottom) {
        \pic (L3E1) {nonfillable elective subject={Subject}}; & &
        \pic (L3E2) {nonfillable elective subject={Subject}}; \\
        & \pic (L3E3) {nonfillable elective subject={Subject}};  & \\
    };
    \matrix[manoooh] (mat4) at ({\LstMatXShifts[4]},{\LstMatYShifts[4]}) {
        & \pic[draw=red] (26) {nonfillable subject={Subject AA}}; & \\
        \pic (27) {nonfillable subject={Subject AB}}; & & \pic (28) {nonfillable subject={Subject AC}}; \\
        & \pic (29) {nonfillable subject={Subject AD}}; & \\
        & \pic (30) {nonfillable subject={Subject AE}}; & \\
        & \pic (31) {nonfillable subject={Subject AF}}; & \\
        & \pic (32) {nonfillable subject={Subject AG}}; & \\
    };
    \matrix[manooohE] (matE4) at ({\LstMatXShifts[4]},\mymatbottom) {
        \pic (L4E1) {nonfillable elective subject={Subject}}; \\
    };
    \matrix[manoooh] (mat5) at ({\LstMatXShifts[5]},{\LstMatYShifts[5]}) {
         \pic (33) {nonfillable subject={Subject AH}};  \\
         \pic (34) {nonfillable subject={Subject AI}};  \\
         \pic[draw=red] (35) {nonfillable subject={Subject AJ}};  \\
         \pic (36) {nonfillable subject={Subject AK}};  \\
    };
    \matrix[manooohE] (matE5) at ({\LstMatXShifts[5]},\mymatbottom) {
         \pic (L5E1) {nonfillable elective subject={Subject}};  \\
         \pic (L5E2) {nonfillable elective subject={Subject}};  \\
         \pic (L5E3) {nonfillable elective subject={Subject}};  \\
         \pic (L5E4) {nonfillable elective subject={Subject}};  \\
         \pic (L5E5) {nonfillable elective subject={Subject}};  \\
    };
 \end{scope}
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\groupwidth}{0}
 \pgfmathsetmacro{\lastwidth}{0}
 \foreach \X in {0,...,5} %<- if you have more or less matrices, adjust 3       
 {
  \node[anchor=south,yshift=1cm,align=center,font=\LARGE\bfseries\boldmath] 
  at (mat\X |-matrices.north) (L\X) {Level $\X$}; 
  \ifnodedefined{matE\X}{% has inlay
   \node[xshift=1em,anchor=south west,font=\LARGE\bfseries,opacity=0] (matEl\X) at (matE\X.north west) {Electives};
   \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
   \path let \p1=($(mat\X.north east)-(mat\X.south west)$) in
   node[fit=(matE\X) (matEl\X),inner ysep=5mm,fill=blue!30,rounded
   corners=40pt,minimum width=\x1-2*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/fit sep},
   inner xsep=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/fit sep}](F\X){};
   \node[xshift=1em,anchor=south west,font=\LARGE\bfseries] 
   (matEl\X) at ([xshift=1.3em]F\X.west|-matEl\X.center) {Electives};
   \end{pgfonlayer}
   \path let \p1=($(mat\X.north east)-(mat\X.south west)$),
    \p2=($(F\X.north east)-(F\X.south west)$),
    \n1={max(abs(\y1)/2+abs(\y2)/2+0*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/inlay top sep},\mymatbottom)}
      in 
    \pgfextra{\xdef\mymatbottom{\n1}
       \ifnum\X=0
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\groupwidth}{0}
       \else    
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\groupwidth}{\groupwidth+max(\x1,\x2)/2+\lastwidth/2+2*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/fit sep}+\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/fit dist}}
       \fi
       \pgfmathsetmacro{\lastwidth}{max(\x1,\x2)+8*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/fit sep}}
       \xdef\lastwidth{\lastwidth}
       \xdef\groupwidth{\groupwidth}     
       \pgfmathsetmacro{\myheight}{max(\y1+\y2+%
         \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/inlay top sep}+\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/matrix top sep},%
         \myheight)}
       \xdef\myheight{\myheight}
       \pgfmathsetmacro{\myshift}{(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/inlay top sep}+\y2)/2}
       \ifnum\X=0
       \xdef\LstMatYShifts{\myshift pt}
       \xdef\LstMatXShifts{0pt}
       \else
       \xdef\LstMatYShifts{\LstMatYShifts,\myshift pt}
       \xdef\LstMatXShifts{\LstMatXShifts,\groupwidth pt}
       \fi};    
   % the fit parameters determine the shape of the background rectangles
   \begin{pgfonlayer}{behind}
   \node[fit=(L\X) (mat\X) (matrices.south-|mat\X.south)
   (matE\X) (matEl\X),inner ysep=8mm,inner xsep=4*\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/fit sep},
   fill=orange!30,rounded corners=50pt](F\X){};
   \end{pgfonlayer}}{% no inlay
   \path 
    let \p1=($(mat\X.north east)-(mat\X.south west)$),
     \n1={max(abs(\y1)/2,\mymatbottom)}
      in 
     \pgfextra{\xdef\mymatbottom{\n1}
       \ifnum\X=0
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\groupwidth}{0}
       \else    
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\groupwidth}{\groupwidth+\x1/2+\lastwidth/2+\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/fit dist}}
       \fi
       \xdef\groupwidth{\groupwidth}
       \xdef\lastwidth{\x1}
       \pgfmathsetmacro{\myheight}{max(\y1+\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/matrix top sep},\myheight)} 
       \xdef\myheight{\myheight}
       \ifnum\X=0
       \xdef\LstMatYShifts{0pt}
       \xdef\LstMatXShifts{0pt}
       \else
       \xdef\LstMatYShifts{\LstMatYShifts,0pt}
       \xdef\LstMatXShifts{\LstMatXShifts,\groupwidth pt}
       \fi};   
   % the fit parameters determine the shape of the background rectangles
   \begin{pgfonlayer}{behind}
   \node[fit=(L\X) (mat\X) (matrices.south-|mat\X.south),inner ysep=8mm,
   fill=orange!30,rounded corners=50pt](F\X){};
   \end{pgfonlayer}
   }
  }
 \makeatletter
 \immediate\write\@mainaux{\xdef\string\mymatbottom{-\mymatbottom}\relax}
 \immediate\write\@mainaux{\xdef\string\myheight{\myheight}\relax}
 \immediate\write\@mainaux{\xdef\string\LstMatYShifts{{\LstMatYShifts}}\relax}
 \immediate\write\@mainaux{\xdef\string\LstMatXShifts{{\LstMatXShifts}}\relax}
 \makeatother

    % From https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/480685/152550

    % now add the arrows.

    \gdef\LstCon{%
        {
        "{2,...,9}",%subjects that 0 links
        "{2,10/5,13/5,14/5}",%subjects that 1 links
        "{11,14}",%subjects that 2 links
        "{10,13,14,25/13}",%subjects that 3 links
        "{36/{12,21,29}}",%subjects that 4 links
        }
    }
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\mylst}{\LstCon[0]}
    \foreach \X in {0,...,\totalnodes} {
        \begin{scope}[ocg={name={Arrow\X},ref=myArrow\X,status=visible}]
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\huenum}{\X*0.75*(1/\totalnodes)}
            \definecolor{mycolor}{hsb}{\huenum,1,1}
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\mylst}{\LstCon[\X]}
            %\typeout{\X:\mylst}
            \foreach \Y/\myalong in \mylst {
             \ifx\myalong\Y
                %\typeout{\X:\Y,empty}
                \draw[-latex,mycolor,very thick] (\X-Title.east) 
                        to[manoooh curve] (\Y-Title.west);
                \else
             %\typeout{\X:\Y\space and\space \myalong}
             \draw[-latex,mycolor,very thick] (\X-Title.east) 
                    [along node/.list/.expanded=\myalong]
                    to[manoooh curve] (\Y-Title.west);
             \fi
            }
        \end{scope}
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{Form}
\flushleft
\qquad\parbox{0.4\linewidth}{\hypersetup{pdfborder={0 0 0}}%
    % list of OCGs, space separated
    \def\ocglist{}%
    \foreach \X in {0,...,\totalnodes} {\xdef\ocglist{\ocglist\space myArrow\X}}
    \fbox{%
    \parbox{12cm}{%
            % on/off All
            \showocg{\ocglist}{\fboxsep=1pt\fbox{\rule{0pt}{1.7ex}on}}/%
            \hideocg{\ocglist}{\fboxsep=1pt\fbox{\rule{0pt}{1.7ex}off}} All\\%
            % checkboxes
            % \begin{multicols}{4}
            \foreach \X in {0,...,\totalnodes} {%          
            \layerCheckBox{}{myArrow\X}{on}\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=-1ex]%
                        \pgfmathsetmacro{\huenum}{\X*0.75*(1/\totalnodes)}\definecolor{mycolor}{hsb}{\huenum,1,1}\draw[-latex,mycolor,very thick] (0,0) -- (1,0);%
                    \end{tikzpicture}\qquad%
            }%
             %   \end{multicols}
        }
    }
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I have a problem: I need to add arrows apart from the `\foreach`. Do you remember this question: [Design an algorithm capable of predicting collisions to choose alternative path using `tikzpicture` environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/480836/152550)? Well, I need to add new arrows, but them are not shown in `parbox`. Do you know how can the arrows appear?

Comment: For example, add these lines of code outside `\foreach` but inside the `tikzpicture`: (1) `\pgfmathsetmacro{\huenumm}{18*0.75*(1/\totalnodes)}` (2) `\definecolor{mycolor2}{hsb}{\huenumm,1,1}` (3) `\draw[-latex,mycolor2,very thick] (18-Title.east) to[manoooh curve=1.6] (29-Title.west);`. If you compile then this new arrow is not shown, which is reasonable, but I do not know how to add it to the list.

Comment: @manooooh That's a tough problem because I do not know how the ocgx stuff works. I would guess that the solution is to add these arrows to the lists after you have used the list to draw the arrows. That is, (1) use smaller lists to draw the arrows, (2) draw additional arrows "by hand" **and add them to the lists afterwards**, (3) do the ocgx with the full lists. Does that make sense? P.S. will go to basketball now...

Comment: I do not think that makes sense at all. I think that if we create smaller lists and then add it to a general list the order will not be preserver: we will have the first "X" arrows in hue gradient and then the last "Y" arrows that have a new hue gradient of colors, so the colors would be mixed, isn't it? However I am not sure how the `ocgx` stuff work, too.

Comment: @manooooh Oh, but then I either completely misunderstand your question, the ocgx code, or both.