# Increasing sample (class) size of colorbrewer

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, color

Is it possible to extend the number of samples used when choosing a colorbrewer style for a collection of curves? For instance this

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usetikzlibrary{colorbrewer, pgfplots.colorbrewer}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colormaps}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document} 
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[cycle list/YlOrRd-9, % Classes max out at 9 it seems
             cycle multi list={YlOrRd-9},]
            \foreach \N in {1,...,10}{
                \addplot {x + \N};
                \addlegendentryexpanded{${\N}$}
            }

        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

will cycle through just 9 colors and then begin again from the beginning:

[image]
Is there a function to be used within the for loop that may sample the color spectrum more finely?

Comment: Does [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/480466) come close?

Comment: Yep that's basically what I need.. Thanks. I guess I don't really need colorbrewer colors, but it would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
colormap/YlOrRd-9, % define color map, not cycle list
cycle list={[colors of colormap={0,50,...,1000}]}
```

The latter line lets you define a cycle list based on the colours in the active colour map. In `colors of colormap` you define a list of numbers from 0 to 1000.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable} % loads pgfplots which loads tikz
\usetikzlibrary{colorbrewer, pgfplots.colorbrewer}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colormaps}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document} 
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            colormap/YlOrRd-9, % define color map, not cycle list
            cycle list={[colors of colormap={0,50,...,1000}]}
          ]
            \foreach \N in {1,...,20}{
                \addplot +[line width=4pt] {x + \N};
                \addlegendentryexpanded{${\N}$}
            }

        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```