# colorbrewer with pgfplots and const plots

Tags: pgfplots, color

I'm trying to get `pgfplots` working with the `colorbrewer` library. So far, the example in the accepted answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/425494/colorbrewer-with-pgfplot-1-15) works for me, but as soon as I add options to the `\addplot` command, the colors are gone and all plots are drawn in black.

MWE: The following document produces black plots, and removing the `[const plot]` option fixes this, but I really do need to specify this and other options.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colorbrewer}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    cycle list/Dark2,
]
\addplot[const plot] {rnd};
\addplot[const plot] {rnd-1};
\addplot[const plot] {rnd-2};
\addplot[const plot] {rnd-3};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Is this a known issue with workarounds etc. or am I doing somethig wrong?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Replacing `\addplot [...]` by `\addplot+ [...]` should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you for the hint @StefanPinnow, that actually worked!

Comment: Shall I write an answer which you accept or shall we close the question as "solved in the comments"?

Comment: I'll happily accept your answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either move `const plot` to the `axis` options or replace `\addplot [...]` by `\addplot+ [...]`. The latter is needed, because otherwise *only* the given optional arguments are used. The difference to the `+` is, that then the optional arguments are *appended*.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.16
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usepgfplotslibrary{colorbrewer}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        cycle list/Dark2,
        const plot,
    ]
        \addplot {rnd};
        \addplot {rnd-1};
        \addplot {rnd-2};
        \addplot {rnd-3};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]