# colorbrewer cycle list not showing markers

Tags: pgfplots

I'm trying to use the colorbrewer library but I'm unable to reproduce the plots found [in this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119161/pre-defined-color-cycles-%C3%A0-la-rcolorbrewer/350086). Although the colors seem to be ok, I can't get the markers right. Do I have to explicitly state the marker in each line? This is the code I have so far:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usepgfplotslibrary{colorbrewer}


\begin{document}

\pgfplotsset{cycle list/Dark2}

\begin{tikzpicture}         
    \begin{loglogaxis}[]

\addplot+ [] table[row sep=crcr]{%
0.184336225523003       0.5732577932974867 \\
0.09731519605337209 0.17515134885908823 \\
0.047909648908800985    0.046898347944650795 \\
0.024262955029476976    0.012377139605563326 \\
}
   ;

\addplot+ [] table[row sep=crcr]{%
0.184336225523003   0.3633379688472427 \\
0.09731519605337209 0.09683966888638465 \\
0.047909648908800985    0.024779440434761386 \\
0.024262955029476976    0.00630727204643381 \\
}
 ;

\addplot+ [] table[row sep=crcr]{%
0.184336225523003   0.04378172643874487\\
0.09731519605337209 0.002999869392740562\\
0.047909648908800985    0.00018383371004886438\\
0.024262955029476976    1.1219427919932696e-05\\
}
 ;

   \end{loglogaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As is written in the PGFPlots manual section 5.2.1:

> Note that `cycle lists` shipped with `colorbrewer` merely consist of *colors*. However, a good `cycle list` typically also comes with markers and perhaps line style variations. In order to combine a pure color-based `cycle list` with markers, you should make use of the features `cycle multi list`, `cycle multiindex list`, and `cycle multiindex* list`, ...

So the answer is, yes, you have to either provide a marker to each `\addplot` command or define a proper `cycle list`.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.15
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usepgfplotslibrary{colorbrewer}
    \pgfplotsset{
        % initialize Dark2
        cycle list/Dark2,
        % combine it with 'mark list*':
        cycle multiindex* list={
            mark list*\nextlist
            Dark2\nextlist
        },
    }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{loglogaxis}[
        table/row sep=crcr,
    ]

        \addplot table {
            0.184336225523003       0.5732577932974867 \\
            0.09731519605337209     0.17515134885908823 \\
            0.047909648908800985    0.046898347944650795 \\
            0.024262955029476976    0.012377139605563326 \\
        };

        \addplot table {
            0.184336225523003       0.3633379688472427 \\
            0.09731519605337209     0.09683966888638465 \\
            0.047909648908800985    0.024779440434761386 \\
            0.024262955029476976    0.00630727204643381 \\
        };

        \addplot table {
            0.184336225523003       0.04378172643874487\\
            0.09731519605337209     0.002999869392740562\\
            0.047909648908800985    0.00018383371004886438\\
            0.024262955029476976    1.1219427919932696e-05\\
        };
    \end{loglogaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: I figured that if I don't put the `+` sign after `\addplot` in the document I'm using (which contains many more figures, it doesn't work. Any ideas why?

Comment: @aaragon The `+` indicates that the options given in the following `[]` should be *appended* to the settings given by the active cycle list. If you don't have the `+`, the style in the cycle list is *replaced* by whatever you put in the brackets. If you don't have anything in the brackets, you get a black line, because that is the TikZ default.

Answer (score 4):

From the `pgfplots` documentation:

> Note that cycle lists shipped with `colorbrewer` merely consist of
>   colors. However, a good cycle list typically also comes with markers
>   and perhaps line style variations. In order to combine a pure
>   color-based cycle list with markers, you should make use of the
>   features `cycle multi list`, `cycle multiindex list`, and `cycle multiindex* list`, for example using:
>
> ```
> \pgfplotsset{
>     % initialize Set1-5:
>     cycle list/Set1-5,
>     % combine it with ’mark list*’:
>     cycle multiindex* list={
>         mark list*\nextlist
>         Set1-5\nextlist
>     },
> }
> ```
>
> Please refer to the reference manual for `cycle multiindex* list` for
>   details.

You can reuse the given example, replacing `Set1-5` with whatever set you need.