# Automatic use of colors from color map for high contrast in pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'd like to setup a color scheme for my whole document. So I would like for a plot with 2 lines to have the two colors furthest apart selected (eg blue and red), for 3 lines blue, purple, red and so on. So far I only managed to get this working for one plot with predefined steps as my MWE shows. Is there a way to do this nicely?
Thanks!

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[cmyk]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage[english]{babel}


\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usetikzlibrary{
        pgfplots.colorbrewer,
    }
    \pgfplotsset{
        cycle from colormap manual style/.style={
            x=3cm,y=10pt,ytick=\empty,
            stack plots=y,
            every axis plot/.style={line width=2pt},
        },
    }
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
colormap name=viridis,
cycle list={
[colors of colormap={0,100,...,1000}]},
%
cycle from colormap manual style,
]
\addplot coordinates {(0,1) (0.5,1) (1,1)};
\addplot coordinates {(0,1) (0.5,1) (1,1)};
\addplot coordinates {(0,1) (0.5,1) (1,1)};
\addplot coordinates {(0,1) (0.5,1) (1,1)};
\addplot coordinates {(0,1) (0.5,1) (1,1)};
\addplot coordinates {(0,1) (0.5,1) (1,1)};
\addplot coordinates {(0,1) (0.5,1) (1,1)};
\addplot coordinates {(0,1) (0.5,1) (1,1)};
\addplot coordinates {(0,1) (0.5,1) (1,1)};
\addplot coordinates {(0,1) (0.5,1) (1,1)};
\addplot coordinates {(0,1) (0.5,1) (1,1)};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}



\end{document}
```

Comment: You are already loading the `colorbrewer` library, but don't use any of the colormaps that this library provides. I would simply use these instead of using the default colormap `hot`. (See e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/350086/95441)

Comment: Thanks. Ideally the solution I'm looking for will either skip certain colors or select a color list depending on graphs eg GnBu-3 vs GnBu-7. That being said for the colorbrewer ones I'd like to also skip the fist ones as they are too light in my opinion for plots. But this is another issue, I also don't mind making my own list.

Comment: I am not sure if your question is answered now, but in case not, you can make your own colormap from an already existing one e.g.  with `indices of colormap` which should do the trick in your case. For other methods have a look at section "Building Colormaps based on other Colormaps" in the [PGFPlots manual v1.16 on page 199ff.](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf#page=199).

Comment: Thanks for your help! This is almost what I'm looking for, however I'm still looking for a way to automatically select a subset of a color map depending on how many charts there are in a pgf plot. So that I don't have to define the subset for each individual plot and so that I am able to change the color map globaly

Comment: Unfortunately, this is impossible. But you can use ColorBrewer's "Qualitative Schemes" (see section 5.2.4 in [PGFPlots manual v1.16 on page 423](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf#page=423). There you can choose a `colormap`/`cycle list` with the maximum value and it will do what you want.